# How do I use java.util.Scanner with integers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just started learning java and I want to make a simple program where it requests the persons
name, outputs the name then asks for the thier favorite number. It will then compare their number
to the number 6 and will output something depending on if the number is larger or smaller than 6.

I am getting a "String to int convert" error in Netbeans which has to do with the scanner.
Hopefully I am asking this correctly but how can I make the scanner pick-up integers?
Thanks

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creating an instance of the scanner class.
        // Gets name and numbers.
        Scanner getName = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner getNumber = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Holds name and number
        String userName;
        int userNumber;

        // Asks for the users name.
        // Holds name in userName.
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        userName = getName.nextLine();

        //Reponds with the users name.
        System.out.println("Hello" + userName + "!");

        //Asks for favorite number.
        // Holds number in userNumber.
        System.out.println("What is your favorite number?");
        userNumber = getNumber.nextLine();

        // Checks if users number is larger than 6.
        if (userNumber > 6) {
            // Stuff goes here.
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: In order to learn Java API, you must have `documentation` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use only one `Scanner` for one input stream:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And after that you should use it's methods to get integers:

```
String name = in.nextLine();
int number = in.nextInt();
```

To be sure, you should read the documentation for `Scanner`:

1. [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
2. [Scanner::nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())
3. [Scanner::nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

Comment: Oh! I didnt know I could use one scanner as one input stream for all. Thanks

Comment: Need to wait 8 minutes. Thanks a lot though. I probably should read the docs. Im just reading a random Java book I have and looking at some code then changing it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Javadoc page for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Just pointing the documentation is OK for comments, but is not real answer.

Comment: I believe it is an answer. I checked for the answer to the OP's question on the page - having to work it out themselves given the documentation is beneficial for answering their own questions in the future. Is it a followed convention to not provide documentation in an answer, or what?

Comment: Yes, it is, you can give link to documentation in a comment, if you like (when you have enough reputation)